# Rails 3 Routes: controller spec doesn't match member routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, controller, routes, member

I'm trying to write a spec to a member controller action that suppose to points to "/admin/projects/:id/some_action", the routes.rb file has the following content:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :projects do
    member do
      get :some_action
    end
  end
end
```

So, when I run $ rake routes I got the right url /admin/projects/:id/some_action, but in the controller spec I got a dammed error.

```
describe Admin::ProjectsController do
  it "should get the action" do
    project = mock_model(:project, :id => 1)
    get :some_action, {:id => project.id}
  end
end
```

The result is always the same:

```
Failure/Error: get :some_action, {:id => 1}
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:id=>1, :controller=>"admin/projects", :action=>"some_action"}
```

Someone pass through this kind of problem? Any suggestion to solve it?

I really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: I saw that some people got a similar problem, caused by a before_filter, but I have a before { sign_in user } for devise authentication, and specs over the projects_controller REST routes fully working!.

Comment: Hey dudes! I fix the problem, I don't know why, but when I upgrade Rspec from 2.7.0 to 2.8.0 the bug goes away. If any other guy get a similar problem this could be a solution. Look at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4401, maybe your problem is a Rails bug too.

Comment: I have the same problem where route does not match when controller is scoped in a namespace and id is passed in the route.
Anyone able to figure this out ?